# How to get facebook comment notifications from my social plugin

Tags: facebook

This site is great and I hope you can help with my problem.

I have added a facebook comment box to all posts on my wordpress site using plugin called [facebook comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/)

The problem I have is not all comments are showing in my facebook comment moderation box.

1. How can I see all the comments?
2. How can I sign up to `comment.create` in the [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments).

The command looks like this:

```
{
    href: "",         /* Open Graph URL of the Comment Plugin */
    commentID: "",    /* The commentID of the new comment */
}
```

Where do I put this code?

Thanks in advance.

Donna